# how to create view in oracle sql 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, create-view

```
SQL> CREATE VIEW  "[my_view]" as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000;
```

> CREATE VIEW  "[my_view]" as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000
>                * ERROR at line 1: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

```
SQL> select * from "[my_view]";
```

> select * from "[my_view]"
>                 * ERROR at line 1: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

This is my code. Whats wrong with me?

Comment: Square brackets `[..]` are invalid for SQL identifiers. See the manual for details: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129

Answer (score 1):

[ ] are not allowed in view name while creating them, your query should look like this

```
create view My_View as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000;
```

For more info please refer to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF01504)

Comment: SQL> create view My_View as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000;
create view My_View as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: You must have been granted the CREATE VIEW (to create a view in your schema) either explicitly or through a role. You are not having sufficient privileges to create views.

Comment: how can i solve this insufficient privileges problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that you can add [ ] to the name of a view, try with "[My_View]" but you must do the select with "[My_View]" too.

Comment: SQL> create view  "[my_view]" as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000;
create view  "[my_view]" as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges


SQL> select * from "[my_view]";
select * from "[my_view]"
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: how can i solve this insufficient privileges problem?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not use brackets for identifier "quotation". Correct syntax is:

```
create view my_view as ...
```

or

```
create view "MY_VIEW" as ..
```

Using quotation does create the view by exact that name including upper and lower case while without it it will be transformed to the database standard case setting. Using Oracle **my_view** will be **MY_VIEW**.

**EDIT:** 
Additional you need the **create any view** privilege to create a view. I assume you have only a user on your tablespace, that is allowed to use views but not to create one.

Comment: SQL> create view my_view as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000;
create view my_view as select ename, sal from emp where sal>2000
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

Comment: where is your answer?

Comment: I updated my original answer with an EDIT block. That is common practice here at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW  view_name
AS
select f_name, l_name
FROM table_name(s)  
where (--This is the place for terms);
```

Comment: Hi pourya.meamrian, welcome to SO. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question will make it more useful for others in the future. Please consider updating your answer with some explanatory notes. Thanks